How can I use a new library in an older version project?
I am new to Flutter and currently facing a situation where I need to add an auto-capture feature for face recognition. However, the project uses an older Flutter version that cannot be upgraded, so I cannot integrate the required library.
My code 

File AndoidManifest.xml

    package="com.example.test_project">
   <application
        android:label="test_project"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
           android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

       <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
            This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>


File build.gradle

   ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
   repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
   }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
   project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
   project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}


File build.gradle (app)

def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
   localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
       localProperties.load(reader)
   }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
   throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
   flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
   flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
   compileSdkVersion 34  

   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }

   kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = '1.8'
   }

   sourceSets {
       main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
   }

   defaultConfig {
       // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
       applicationId "com.example.test_project"
       minSdkVersion 25
       targetSdkVersion 34
       versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
       versionName flutterVersionName
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
           // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
       profile {
           initWith debug
       }
   }
}

flutter {
   source '../..'
}

String storageUrl = System.env.FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL ?: "https://storage.googleapis.com"
repositories {
   maven {
       url '/Users/phannhattan/Work/KAS/face_camera_module/build/host/outputs/repo'
   }
   maven {
       url "$storageUrl/download.flutter.io"
   }
}

dependencies {

   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
   debugImplementation 'com.kas.face_camera_module:flutter_debug:1.0'
   profileImplementation 'com.kas.face_camera_module:flutter_profile:1.0'
   releaseImplementation 'com.kas.face_camera_module:flutter_release:1.0'
}


File MainActivity

package com.example.test_project

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineCache
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.channel";
    private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL);

        channel.setMethodCallHandler {call, result ->
            if(call.method == "openFlutterModule") {
                result.success("abc")
                startActivity(
                    FlutterActivity
                        .withNewEngine()
                        .initialRoute("/face_camera")
                        .build(this)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
 


File main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('com.example.channel');

  Future<void> navigateToModule() async {
    try {
      // Gửi lệnh xuống Kotlin
      String test = await platform.invokeMethod('openFlutterModule');
    } catch (e) {
      print("Failed to invoke method: $e");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: navigateToModule,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
 


File pubspec.yaml
name: test_projectdescription: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment: sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies: flutter: sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies: flutter_test: sdk: flutter

flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter: uses-material-design: true


My solution: I tried creating a new Flutter module with the latest version, integrating the library, and calling it from the native code in the older Flutter project to receive the returned image file. Unfortunately, I am unable to display the screen or retrieve the file through the Flutter module.

Could anyone provide me with an alternative solution or guide me on how to properly implement my current approach in android and ios? Thank, so much.



Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You need to establish a process to regularly update Flutter (and other dependencies/tools for that matter). That is needed to be compatible with other software you try to integrate and to fix known security vulnerabilities. I'm not sure if there is a workaround possible for this specific library (which one? Please be more specific), but in general you will have to decide at some point what is more important: Implementing new features or preserving the status quo. Oftentimes you cannot have both.

Currently, source use flutter version 2.10.5 and I want to integrate the face_camera library to automatically take pictures when a face is detected. Is there any way I can implement this functionality without upgrading the Flutter version?
